# Ansible: execute a task/handler BEFORE another one only if the second changes something

Tags: ansible

I need to change configuration files for a service. This change must be done with this service stopped.
I can do something like this:

```
- name: stop service
  service:
     name: my_service
     state: stopped

- name: change config
  copy:
     src: my_config
     dest: /etc/my_service/my_config

- name: start service
  service:
      name: my_service
      status: started
```

The issue with this is that `my_service` is stopped in any case, even when the `copy` task has 'changed' nothing.

How can I tell ansible to only run 'stop service' when 'change config' has `changed: true`?

Answer (score 3):

You can duplicate the "change config" task and first run it with `check_mode: yes` option, register the result and then run (or not) all three tasks with a condition based on the result, for example in a block.

Comment: Thanks @techraf. That worked and resolved my issue.